# PostgreSQL: Using BIT VARYING column for bitmask operations

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, bitmask

Having used bitmasks for years as a C programmer I'm attempting to do something similar in Postgres and it's not working as I expected. So here is a table definition with 2 columns:

```
    dummy 
    ( 
        countrymask  BIT VARYING (255) not null,  -- Yes it's a pretty wide bitmask
        countryname  CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL, 
    );
```

So, some data in the "dummy" table would be:

[image]

Now, what is the SQL to return Albania, Armenia and Belarus with one select using the mask?? (i.e.  '100010001')

I thought it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DUMMY WHERE (countrymask & (b'100010001')) <> 0;
```

But I get a type mismatch.. which I'd love some assistance on.
But also, is this going to work when the typecasting is sorted out?

Comment: A relational database isn't a C program. Using bitmasks isn't something that fits well with the relational model. A properly normalized model will be easier to use. `create table dummy (id integer primary key, country_name varchar(100))`

Comment: well, we denormalize tables all the time for performance, hence snowflake schema's etc. there are 10's of millions of rows in this database and we would like to select out different sets of countries on demand. so the set has all country names in it - roughly 200 independent countries. using standard "IN" clause is very slow, especially with country names (text) forces multiple table scans. Any thoughts on that are welcome.

Comment: I don't see how an IN clause would result in *multiple* table scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use bit strings of the same length throughout, that is `bit(255)`, and store all the leading zeros.

This would be simpler if you could use integers and do

```
WHERE countrymask & 273 <> 0
```

but there are no integer types with 255 bits supporting the `&` operator.

Anyway, such a query could never use an index, which is no problem with a tiny table like `dummy`, but it could be a problem if you want to scan a bigger table.

In a way, that data model violates the first normal form, because it stores several country codes in a single datum. I think that you would be happier with a classical relational model: have a country table that has a numerical primary key filled with a sequence, and use a mapping table to associate rows in another table with several countries.

An alternative would be to store the countries for a row as an array of country identifiers (`bigint[]`). Then you can use the “overlaps” operator `&&` to scan the table for rows that have any of the countries in a given array. Such an operation [can be made fast with a GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html).

Comment: Excellent response, thanks Laurenz. The problem I'm facing is that the table has over 20M rows, with a 'country' column. App/user can select any of the countries in the world - as in the example above, and the app is to return all the rows that corrispond to that. Using an "IN" clause in SQL results in multiple table scans. So bitmasking seemed one way to solve that. Any thoughts on better mechanisms are welcome.

Comment: I added a suggestion for that to the answer. Arrays could do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I think that's the answer i need. For reference, after I read your post I went to this page to see an implementation. https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index